# Typing in an invalid city results in nothing happening in the UI and an error in the console

Tags: javascript

```js
const key = '7kjwwl6sBk8YIRy5cStcQxH1AkHYuZk6 ';

//get weather info
const getWeather = async (id) => {
  const base = 'https://dataservice.accuweather.com/currentconditions/v1/';
  const query = `${id}?apikey=${key}`;

  const  response = await fetch(base + query);
  const data = await response.json();

  return data[0];

};


//get city info
const getCity = async (city) => {
  const base = 'https://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/search';
  const query = `?apikey=${key}&q=${city}`;

  const response = await fetch(base + query);
  const data = await response.json();

  return data[0];
};



const cityForm = document.querySelector('form');
const card = document.querySelector('.card');
const details = document.querySelector('.details');
const time = document.querySelector('img.time');
const icon = document.querySelector('.icon img');

const updateUI =(data) => {

  console.log(data);
  const cityDets = data.cityDets;
  const weather = data.weather;

  //update details template
  details.innerHTML =` 
  <h5 class="my-3">${cityDets.EnglishName}</h5>
  <div class="my-3">${weather.WeatherText}</div>
  <div class="display-4 my-4">
    <span>${weather.Temperature.Metric.Value}</span>
    <span>&deg;C</span>
  </div> 
  `;
//update the night/day & icon imgs
const iconSrc = `scripts/icons/${weather.WeatherIcon}.svg`;
icon.setAttribute('src', iconSrc);

let timesrc = null;
if(weather.IsDayTime){
  timeSrc = 'scripts/day.svg';
} else {

  timeSrc = "scripts/night.svg";
}
time.setAttribute('src', timeSrc);



  //remove d-none class if present
  if(card.classList.contains('d-none')){
    card.classList.remove('d-none');
  }


};

const updateCity = async (city) => {

  const cityDets = await getCity(city);
  const weather = await getWeather(cityDets.Key);

  return {
    cityDets: cityDets,
    weather: weather
  };
   
};

cityForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  // prevent default action
  e.preventDefault();

  //get city value
  const city = cityForm.city.value.trim();
  cityForm.reset();

  //update the ui with new city
  updateCity(city)
  .then(data => updateUI(data))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

});
```

```css
body{
    background: #ffffff88;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    font-size: 0.8em;
  }
  
  .container{
    max-width: 400px;
  }

  .icon {
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100px;
    margin-bottom: -50px;
  }

  h1 {
    font-family: 'Mansalva', cursive;
    font-size:50px;

  }

  label {
      font-size: 15px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mansalva&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Weather Ninja</title>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container my-5 mx-auto">
        <h1 class="text-muted text-center my-4">Weather Ninja</h1>
        <form class="change-location my-4 text-center text-muted">
            <label for="city">Enter a location for weather information</label>
            <input type="text" name="city" class="form-control p-4">
        </form>


        <div class="card shadow-lg rounded d-none ">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300" class="time card-img-top" alt="place-holder">
            <div class="icon bg-light mx-auto text-center">
              <img src="" alt="results">

            </div>

            <div class="text-muted text-uppercase text-center details">
                <h5 class="my-3">City name</h5>
                <div class="my-3">Weather condition</div>
                <div class="display-4 my-4">
                    <span>temp</span>
                    <span>&deg;C</span>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>



    <script src="forecast.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Hi im working on a weather app. My app will return the correct weather info but when I type in a non existent value purposely, it says unable to get property but I want to log the error to the console. I tried doing that on line 97 in my app.js file. Can someone please tell me what im doing wrong.----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Answer (score 0):

I can see the error being logged at below line.

```
 //update the ui with new city
        updateCity(city)
          .then(data => updateUI(data))
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

This will be logged as Info in browser console. If you want as error log, try `console.error(err)` instead.

Try the snippet to see your console statement printed. Just changed `console.log(err)` to `console.log(err.message)` as the SO snippet console seems to not work well with error objects.

```js
const key = 'TxdgOemczF6OGu7F7mMVFtHkGDcKF8W3 ';

//get weather info
const getWeather = async (id) => {
  const base = 'https://dataservice.accuweather.com/currentconditions/v1/';
  const query = `${id}?apikey=${key}`;

  const  response = await fetch(base + query);
  const data = await response.json();

  return data[0];

};


//get city info
const getCity = async (city) => {
  const base = 'https://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/search';
  const query = `?apikey=${key}&q=${city}`;

  const response = await fetch(base + query);
  const data = await response.json();

  return data[0];
};



const cityForm = document.querySelector('form');
const card = document.querySelector('.card');
const details = document.querySelector('.details');
const time = document.querySelector('img.time');
const icon = document.querySelector('.icon img');

const updateErrorUI = () => {
  details.innerHTML = `No data found`;
  if(card.classList.contains('d-none')){
    card.classList.remove('d-none');
  }
}

const updateUI =(data) => {

  console.log(data);
  const cityDets = data.cityDets;
  const weather = data.weather;

  //update details template
  details.innerHTML =` 
  <h5 class="my-3">${cityDets.EnglishName}</h5>
  <div class="my-3">${weather.WeatherText}</div>
  <div class="display-4 my-4">
    <span>${weather.Temperature.Metric.Value}</span>
    <span>&deg;C</span>
  </div> 
  `;
//update the night/day & icon imgs
const iconSrc = `scripts/icons/${weather.WeatherIcon}.svg`;
icon.setAttribute('src', iconSrc);

let timesrc = null;
if(weather.IsDayTime){
  timeSrc = 'scripts/day.svg';
} else {

  timeSrc = "scripts/night.svg";
}
time.setAttribute('src', timeSrc);



  //remove d-none class if present
  if(card.classList.contains('d-none')){
    card.classList.remove('d-none');
  }


};

const updateCity = async (city) => {

  const cityDets = await getCity(city);
  const weather = await getWeather(cityDets.Key);

  return {
    cityDets: cityDets,
    weather: weather
  };
   
};

cityForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  // prevent default action
  e.preventDefault();

  //get city value
  const city = cityForm.city.value.trim();
  cityForm.reset();

  //update the ui with new city
  updateCity(city)
  .then(data => updateUI(data))
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err.message);
    updateErrorUI();
   }
  );

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mansalva&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Weather Ninja</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container my-5 mx-auto">
      <h1 class="text-muted text-center my-4">Weather Ninja</h1>
      <form class="change-location my-4 text-center text-muted">
        <label for="city">Enter a location for weather information</label>
        <input type="text" name="city" class="form-control p-4" />
      </form>

      <div class="card shadow-lg rounded d-none ">
        <img
          src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300"
          class="time card-img-top"
          alt="place-holder"
        />
        <div class="icon bg-light mx-auto text-center">
          <img src="" alt="results" />
        </div>

        <div class="text-muted text-uppercase text-center details">
          <h5 class="my-3">City name</h5>
          <div class="my-3">Weather condition</div>
          <div class="display-4 my-4">
            <span>temp</span>
            <span>&deg;C</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```